# Conditional inner join & CASE

Tags: sql, oracle

Using Oracle. I have a table that looks like this:

```
  COLUMN1  COLUMN2
1 A1       B1
2 A2       B2
3          B3
4 A3
5          B4
6          B5
7 A4       B6
```

I'm using COLUMN1 as the primary key to map to another table. However, some of the rows for COLUMN1 are empty, and in those cases, I am advised to use COLUMN2 values as primary keys (like rows 5 and 6).

1) Is it possible to write a conditional INNER JOIN statement with CASE? Something like

```
CASE WHEN
COLUMN1 IS NULL 
THEN INNER JOIN ...... ON column1 = ....
ELSE
INNER JOIN ...... ON column2 = ....
END (???)
```

2) Another option that my friends suggested to me is to create a new column with row values primarily from COLUMN1 and secondarily from COLUMN2 if COLUMN1 is empty for that row. **How would I do this with NVL and CASE?** The desired esult would be the following, and NEW_COLUMN would be my primary key for mapping:

```
  NEW_COLUMN
1 A1       
2 A2       
3 B3
4 A3
5 B4
6 B5
7 A4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Primary Key column may NOT have repeating values.  In concept, a Primary Key column is a unique identifier for a row, and, as such, may not have NULL values in it. The design may need a join a different way.

Having said that, a conditional JOIN using multiple columns would look like this

```
Select ColA, ColB, ColC
From Table1 T1
Join Table2 T2
    On NVL (T1.Col1, T1.Col2) = NVL (T2.Col01, T2.Col02)
```

You can also generate a new column like this

```
Alter Table1 Add Col3  NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS NVL (Col1, Col2) STORED;
```

Answer (score 1):

`CASE` is an expression, like `+`. It does not control code. You can use the following:

```
select . . .
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t2.col = coalesce(t1.col1, t1.col2)
```

Often, two `left join`s have better performance:

```
select . . .,
       coalesce(t21.colx, t22.colx) as colx
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t21
     on t21.col = t1.col1 left join
     table2 t22
     on t22.col = t1.col2 and t1.col1 is null;
```